# Access Elements of List of Tuples Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a Python (2.7) list with tuples that looks like this: `[Status(ID=806829700194635776, ScreenName=YaziAfrica, Created=Thu Dec 08 11:56:05 +0000 2016, Text=u'RT @thandi25M: DST investment and journey outlined. #sfsa2016 #iamuwc  DDG Tommy Makhode #dstgov https://someurl')]`

And I want to access the ScreenName value ("YaziAfrica") in this case. There may be several hundred of these list tuples so ideally I would loop through the response. I've tried `print(list[1][ScreenName])`but that prompts a `TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Appreciate any help, I can't seem to find something that addresses this example.

Comment: That's not a tuple. Figure out what type it is first.

Comment: Ah, guess I wasn't clear. As far as I can tell (checking the type) it's `I have a Python (2.7) list with tuples`

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list of tuples `list[1][1]` would return `'ScreenName=YaziAfrica'`

`print(list[1][ScreenName])` does not work because ScreenName is not an index of the value `'YaziAfrica'`. Essentially `'ScreenName=YaziAfrica'` is the value, and the index is 1.

Comment: Weird, that doesn't work but this does: `print(x.user.screen_name)` although it only returns one if I have multiple records brought back.